# using not() to exclude children, but does not work

Tags: jquery

I tried to exclude a child class from selector using `not()`function, but it still selects the child class. I know I can use `.parentClass > .childClass` to select all the children classes I want but I have a lot of children classes and just want to exclude one child class.

I have a simple example here (the `p` tag should not have yellow background color):

HTML:

```
<li class='list'>
  <p class='pa'>test</p>
  <button class='btn'>click</button>
</li>
<li class='list'>
  <p class='pa'>test</p>
  <button class='btn'>click</button>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.yellow {
  background-color : yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list:not(.pa)').addClass('yellow');
})
```

Or, you can use the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7n2zhusz/)

Comment: .not only filters the current selection. child nodes are not part of the current selection.

Comment: `$('.list:not(.pa)')` selects elements with the class `list` that don't have the class `pa`. It has nothing to do with children.

Comment: That selector does not do what you think it does.  It says "For all elements with the class `list`, but NOT with the class `.pa`, add the yellow class".  However, your `pa` elements are *children of* the `list` elements, therefore the `:not` does nothing.

Comment: What exactly is your end goal? given you current code and explanation, no list items would get the yellow class if you targeted only list items that didn't have a .pa child. I assume you instead wanted the css to affect the parent but not the child? that's... not something jquery can help you with, and not how css works.

Comment: So what I want is select a parent class which includes many children class, but there is one child class I do not want it to be included in this selection.

Comment: your end goal is still unclear. when you select the parent elements, you aren't selecting the child elements. you can't exclude something you haven't included yet.

Comment: @lilixiaocc You can use $('.list p').not('.pa').parent("li") or $('.list').not(':has(.pa)')

Comment: If you are trying to do what I think you're trying to do, you may have problems doing that even if you do get the syntax right. In a parent element with a specific background colour, giving a child element _no_ background colour will not keep the background colour from displaying behind the child! Edit: oh, that's what Kevin was saying already.

Answer (score 0):

It would filter out `.list` element which doesn't have the class and not for its children. To check on children use jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo class selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list:not(:has(.pa))').addClass('yellow');
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list:not(:has(.pa))').addClass('yellow');
})
```

```css
.yellow {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='list'>
    <p class='pa'>test</p>
    <button class='btn'>click</button>
  </li>
  <li class='list'>
    <p class='pa'>test</p>
    <button class='btn'>click</button>
  </li>
  <li class='list'>
    <p class=''>test</p>
    <button class='btn'>click</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `.filter` to filter out the items which have a child `.pa`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list').filter(function(){
      return $('.pa',this).length == 0;
  }).addClass('yellow');
})
```

```css
.yellow {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='list'>
    <p class='pa'>test</p>
    <button class='btn'>click</button>
  </li>
  <li class='list'>
    <p>test</p>
    <button class='btn'>click</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```